# Additional column in pgfgantt

Tags: pgfgantt

I am working in some Gantt charts using `pfgantt` package. At the moment I have the responsible for the task written after the task label. I would like to have a column after the task label with all the responsible for the tasks. Similar to

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}[
  hgrid,
  % vgrid,
  x unit=4pt,
  y unit title=0.5cm,
  y unit chart=0.6cm,
    time slot format=isodate,
    time slot unit= day,
    calendar week text={W\currentweek},
    % compress calendar,
    title/.append style={shape=rectangle, fill=black!10},
    title height=1,
    bar/.append style={fill=green!20},
    bar height=.6,
    bar label font=\normalsize\color{black},
    group/.append style={fill=green!20},
    group top shift=.6,
    group height=.3,
    group peaks height=.2,
%    bar incomplete/.append style={fill=cyan!40}
  ]{2020-01-01}{2020-03-10}
  \gantttitlecalendar{year, month=name, week=1} \\
    \ganttgroup{Group 1}{2020-01-02 00:00:00}{2020-03-05 00:00:00}\\
    \ganttbar[name=task1]{Task1 - Resp. Jon Plumber}{2020-01-02}{2020-01-07}\\
    \ganttmilestone[name=Mile.1]{Milestone1 - Resp. Alice Plumber}{2020-02-14}
    \end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```